# parsing an xml with node elements using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an xml like below I am trying to parse using jquery and get something like i wrote below java script to parse it.I have tried below code but i am able to get location not in below format as i expect.

Expected Result:

```
S1:E1:https://location1
S2:E2:https://location1
```

xml:

```
<Country>
    <State>
        <id>S1</id>    
        <City>
            <E1>    
               <location>https://location1</location>
            </E1>    
        </City>
        <County>
            <E2>    
               <location>https://location2</location>            
            </E2>
        </County>
    </State>    
    <State>
        <id>S2</id>
        <City>
            <E1>    
               <location>https://location3</location>
            </E1>    
        </City>
        <County>
            <E2>    
               <location>https://location4</location>            
            </E2>    
        </County>    
    </State>
</Country>
```

code

```
var container = $( document.body );    
var xml = '<Country> <State> <id>S1</id> <City> <E1> <location>https://location1</location> </E1> </City> <County> <E2> <location>https://location2</location> </E2> </County> </State> <State> <id>S2</id> <City> <E1> <location>https://location3</location> </E1> </City> <County> <E2> <location>https://location4</location> </E2> </County> </State> </Country>',
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
$xml = $( xmlDoc ),
$location = $xml.find( 'location' );    
container.append( $("<p/>", { "text" : $location.text() }) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like,

```
var container = $( document.body );

var xml = '<Country> <State> <id>S1</id> <City> <E1> <location>https://location1</location> </E1> </City> <County> <E2> <location>https://location2</location> </E2> </County> </State> <State> <id>S2</id> <City> <E1> <location>https://location3</location> </E1> </City> <County> <E2> <location>https://location4</location> </E2> </County> </State> </Country>',
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
$xml = $( xmlDoc ),
$location = $xml.find( 'location' );   // will return all location elements     
$location.each(function(){
    container.append( $("<p/>", { "text" : $(this).text() }) ); 
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/tks6L0bg/)

Updated code to display result with ID

```
var container = $(document.body);

var xml = '<Country> <State> <id>S1</id> <City> <E1> <location>https://location1</location> </E1> </City> <County> <E2> <location>https://location2</location> </E2> </County> </State> <State> <id>S2</id> <City> <E1> <location>https://location3</location> </E1> </City> <County> <E2> <location>https://location4</location> </E2> </County> </State> </Country>',
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
    $xml = $(xmlDoc),
    $location = $xml.find('location'); // will return all location elements     
$location.each(function () {
    container.append($("<p/>", {
        "text": 
            $(this).closest('State').find('id').text() + ':' + // get State ID like S1,S2
            $(this).closest('City').find(':first-child').prop('tagName') + ':' + // get City's location tag like E1,E2
            $(this).text() // get the location text like location1,location2....
    }));
});
```

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/tks6L0bg/2/)

Comment: Thanks but i want to know from where this location came from eg: S1:E1:https://location1
S2:E2:https://location4

Comment: @user2656713 see my updated answer, you need to make the XML in a format to get proper result for location2 and location4, currently it shows `undefined`. You can use a `if-condition` to by pass when the location tag doesn't exists.